# APNS : openssl s_client gethostbyname failure

Tags: ios, openssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to test the connection between my server & Apple's sandbox APNS server with the following command:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.apple.com:2195 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0
```

What is the meaning of `gethostbyname failure`, and what is the cause?

In the same server, telnet to port 2195 is working fine:

```
$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.36.242...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**UPDATE:** If I use IP instead of host name, it works fine:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 17.149.36.242:2195 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
```

OpenSSL is unable to resolve DNS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct name for sandbox is gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, not gateway.sandbox.apple.com.

Comment: Hi Eran, i used openssl s_client –connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert my_cert.pem -key my_cert.pem but i also get same error **gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=0** .. im new too iOS & push notiifcation.. plz provide helpful links or code snippets :)